# Band not recognised - seagrass mapping on GEE

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, classification

```js
// Load Sentinel 2 raw imagery and filter it to all images in 2023.
var S2data = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
    .filterDate('2023-05-01', '2023-08-01')
    .filterBounds(poi)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 40));

// Take median
var S2composite = S2data.median();

// Create Land mask
var B8 = S2composite.select('B8');
var NIR_thres = 500;
var landmask = B8.where(B8.gt(NIR_thres), 0).where(B8.lt(NIR_thres), 1);

// Add Layers to Map
var rgbVis = {min: 0, max: 3000, bands: ['B8']};
Map.addLayer(S2composite, rgbVis, 'S2 NIR Band');
Map.addLayer(landmask.clip(poi), {bands: ['B8'], gamma: 1, max: 1, opacity: 1}, 'S2 Land Mask');



// Classification

// Training data
var seagrass = ee.FeatureCollection('seagrass');
var sand = ee.FeatureCollection('sand');
var trainingPolygons = seagrass.merge(sand);

// Define the bands to use for classification
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'];

// Print the band names of the Sentinel-2 image
print('Band names:', S2composite.bandNames());

// Create a property for the class label and set it to 1 for seagrass and 2 for sand
var training = trainingPolygons.map(function(feature) {
  var classLabel = ee.Number.parse(feature.get('class'));
  return feature.set('class', classLabel);
});

// Train a Random Forest classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: bands
});

// Classify the Sentinel-2 image
var classified = S2composite.select(bands).classify(classifier);

print(trainingPolygons);

// Add the classified image to the map
Map.centerObject(poi, 10);
Map.addLayer(classified, {
  min: 0,
  max: 2,
  palette: ['0000FF', '00FF00', 'FF0000'],  // Blue for sand, Green for seagrass, Red for unclassified
}, 'Seagrass and Sand Classification');
Map.addLayer(poi, {}, 'POI');

// Display the map
Map;
```

And the error I get:

> Seagrass and Sand Classification: Layer error: Property 'B2' is missing.

When I print my bands I get:

```
0: B1
1: B2
2: B3
3: B4
4: B5
5: B6
6: B7
7: B8
```

What should I change to stop getting this error?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to include an initial paragraph where you describe the data and task, so you have a complete problem statement.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, but it looks like your training data haven't actually sampled the composite, so they don't have any B2 properties.